# can somebody tell me what error i have in this BPM

Tags: linq, business-process-management, epicorerp

This code will auto generate a new part number. This is a Post-processing BPM for BO GetNewPart

```
int iPartnum = 0;
string cPartid = string.Empty;
Erp.Tables.Company Company;
foreach (var ttpart_xRow in ttPart)
{
    var ttpartRow = ttpart_xRow;
    Company = (from Company_Row in Db.Company
               where Company_Row.Company == Session.CompanyID
    select Company_Row).FirstOrDefault();
    iPartnum = (decimal)Company["AutoGenerate_c"] + 1;
    cPartid = System.Convert.ToString(iPartnum);
    ttpartRow.PartNum = cPartid;
    Services.Lib.UpdateTableBuffer._UpdateTableBuffer(Company,"AutoGenerate_c", iPartnum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it just not working or is there an error message?

```
Services.Lib.UpdateTableBuffer._UpdateTableBuffer(Company,"AutoGenerate_c", iPartnum);
```

I have personally never used or even seen this Lib item so I can't vouch for it. I would update the object manually inside of a transaction scope because I doubt GetNewPart ever touches that database and therefore probably doesn't create a transaction.

```
using (System.Transactions.TransactionScope txScope = IceDataContext.CreateDefaultTransactionScope())//start the transaction
{
   //Your Logics go here
   Db.Validate();
   txScope.Complete();//commit the transaction
}
```

As a side note, I try to keep these sorts of things off of the company record because nearly every process in the system touches it and I don't want a process to lock it up or cause weird race conditions. I generally like to reserve a record that will only get touched for this specific purpose so I have a UDCodeType/UDCode for this sort of thing.